# Small annoyance with template function

Tags: c++, templates

Ok, let's say I have a function like this

```
template <typename T>
void Func(std::vector<T> x, T alpha = 1)
{
    // ... do stuff
}
```

and I would like to use it with a complex type, like this

```
std::vector<std::complex<double>> x;
Func(x, 5.5);
```

Then the compiler complains (VS2010) that `template parameter 'T' is ambiguous` because it `could be 'double' or 'std::complex<double>'`. Obvious fix, call it like this

```
Func(x, std::complex<double>(5.5));
```

but, that, I don't want. Why can't it be converted to a complex type automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because the first argument causes `T` to be deduced as `std::complex<double>` whereas the second argument causes it to be deduced as `double`. It simply doesn't consider conversions when deducing arguments. Obviously, this makes the deduction ambiguous.

You can force the second argument type to be non-deducable with the help of an `identity` helper:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };

template <typename T>
void Func(std::vector<T> x, typename identity<T>::type alpha = 1)
{
    // ... do stuff
}
```

Comment: I like it! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @demorge Now, if only the standard library defined `std::identity`.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
template<typename T>
struct identity {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
void Func(std::vector<T> x, typename identity<T>::type alpha = 1)
{
    // ... do stuff
}
```

The second argument will not be involved in the template parameter deduction, the vector template argument will be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have a default argument whose type is different from the contained type, just use two different types:

```
template <class T, class U>
void Func(vector<T> x, U y);
```

Comment: This complains that the second template argument cannot be deduced if not provided explicitly. Still waiting for the default template-type parameters for functions...

Comment: Good point. The default argument doesn't work here. I've removed it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like identity helpers and just want it to be convertible, try this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void Func(const std::vector<T>& x, U alphaU = 1)
{
    const T alpha(alphaU); // Convert to T
    // ... do stuff
}
```

**Update:**

Re your comment: I tried it with several compilers at http://liveworkspace.org and this code builds fine for me:

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

template <typename T, typename U>
void Func(const std::vector<T>& x, U alphaU)
{
   const T alpha(alphaU); // Convert to T
   (void) x;
   (void) alpha;
}

template <typename T>
void Func(const std::vector<T>& x)
{
    Func( x, 1 );
}    

int main()
{
   std::vector<std::complex<double>> v(10);
   Func( v, 5.5 );
   Func( v );
}
```

Comment: This complains that the second template argument cannot be deduced if not provided explicitly. Still waiting for the default template-type parameters for functions...

Comment: It happens when you call it like `Func( v );`, pretty annoying.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that by moving the conversion inside the template the compiler will generate a different `Func` for each type passed as the second argument, causing unnecessary code bloat if you use multiple such types.

Comment: Good point. I removed the default param and added an overload instead.